# Using SCSS in spring boot with freemarker and gradle

Tags: css, spring-boot, gradle, sass, freemarker

So I have a `spring boot` project that is using `freemarker` and is built using `gradle`.

This is my `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.9.RELEASE")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.9.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

group = 'some.project'
version = '4'
mainClassName = "some.project.Application"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.tomcat', module: 'tomcat-jdbc'
    }
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker'
}

jar {
    // include all the jars
    from {
        (configurations.runtime).collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'some.project.Application'
    }
}
```

I have decided to start using scss because my css files were becoming a little difficult to manage and keep consistent. However I can't seem to figure out how to get my application to load up scss files. All the scss files are located in `resources/static/scss`, what should I do with them so that they become css and readable by my spring boot application and freemarker?